# Map Library: Client-side or Server-side?

Tags: design, concepts

As I have [already asked here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170078/multi-platform-map-application), I have to implement a Multi-Platform Map application. Now I have [Mapstraction](http://mapstraction.com/) as an option which uses Javascript to implement the desired functionality. My question is, "Is there any reason/benefit to implement such a library (let say, Adapters) in Server-side (in my case, PHP)?"

As these maps are all based on Javascript, there is a big reason to use Javascript again to make the adapter also, so it would not be dependent to PHP, Java, or .NET for example. But is that all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there are no benefits to implementing your adapters on the server-side rather than in JavaScript. In fact you would be better off with JavaScript because it is *the ubiquitous language of the web*; if in the future you decide to re-write your backend using another technology, you wouldn't have to re-write the adapters.

If you're hesitant to go with JavaScript because you don't have enough experience with it, even *then* my suggestion would remain unchanged, because every modern, client-heavy web application demands that you be comfortable with it.

Besides, you're getting a mature, tested JavaScript adapter library - with a fairly permissive BSD license - in the form of Mapstraction, which I mentioned in [my answer to your linked question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/170080/13821), so that's a very good option if you can use it. Either way, I think JavaScript is the way to go for you.